# How can I use variables as part of field names in the MongoDB shell?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongo-shell

How can I use variables as part of field names in the mongodb shell? I am trying to do the following:

```
> var site = "google.com";
> var y = 10;
> var m = 5;

// This fails (field names as concatenation):
> db.test.update({ "domain" : site},
      { $inc : {"counts.year."+y : 1, "counts.month."+m : 1}}, upsert=true);

> Thu Apr 19 19:12:56 SyntaxError: missing : after property id (shell):1

// This works:
> db.test.update({ "domain" : site}, { $inc : {"counts.year.10" : 1,
      "counts.month.5" : 1}}, upsert=true);
```

I guess the problem is in the way the JS object is created: for instance `var t = 10; doc = {t : 0};` works but `var t = 10; doc = {"Test."+t : 0}`; does not. How can I work around this?

Thank you,

/David

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you could try for the JS object:

```
var t = 10;
var doc = {};
doc["Test."+t] = 0;
```

or

```
var t = 10, doc = {};
doc["Test."+t] = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked `var site = "google.com"; var y = 2012; var m = 10; var d = 30; doc = {}; incDoc["counts.year."+y] = 1; incDoc["counts.month."+m] = 1; incDoc["counts.days."+d] = 1; db.test.update({ "domain" : site}, { $inc : incDoc}, upsert=true);`